# Use cedilla in groff .ms type document to export as pdf

Tags: linux, pdf, groff

I'm struggling to use special characters in .ms document. Is there a way to use cedilla in a .ms document to export to pdf using groff?

Comment: You might get better results for groff questions on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cedilla is placed with `\[ac]`. For the common ç, you can use `\[,c]`.

You can also use `\h` to put a cedilla under another character.

```
\[,c] \[ac]\h'-0.45m'S \[ac]\h'-0.45m'c \[ac]\h'-0.45m'o
```

produces

[image]